# Mattson's openmp pi examples: No speed up in the for example

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to run the pi calculation programs included in the Mattson OMP Exercises accompanying the lectures. Of the 3 versions,pi_spmd_simple, pi_spmd_final and pi_loop, the first two scale up as mentioned in the lectures, but the third, using the for pragma with reduction, is slower with two or more threads than with one. Has anybody else seen similar (mis)behaviour? Is there any explanation?
My tests were run on an Intel E6500 Dual Core 2.93GHz CPU running Knoppix 7.4.2 with gcc 4.9.1. We have observed similar behaviour on AMD 4 Core Phenom processor. I have also observed similar issues in even simpler programs with for loops.
The tutorial is in [OpenMP Tutorial](http://tinyurl.com/OpenMP-Tutorial)

Comment: Mind sharing the code?

Comment: The example code by Mattson is surely correct, so the problem must be in whatever modifications you have made or in bad compiler settings or something like that. Will you share the code so we can have a look at it?

Comment: Thank you both. I have no doubt that the Mattson's code is correct.

Comment: I have not included the code as I did not make any modification to the original.  I have in the meantime found out that if compiled with ompicc or if -O3 is given to gcc the executable scales properly. I did not expect  -O3 to have such dramatic effect: without -O3 1 thread 0.75s 2 threads 1.15s, with -O3 1 thread 0.75s 2 threads 0.39s